Hausdorff dimension of the Sierpiński triangle calculated from definition
I already know how to calculate the Hausdorff dimension of the Sierpiński triangle the way it is presented on Hausdorff dimension of Sierpinski triangle less than log3/log2. However, my complaint is that this calculation only looks at a specific cover whereas in the definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) the infimum is taken over all countable covers, so the cover should be more general. Am I missing something here? Can someone please explain?
Also, how do I go about computing the precise dimension from the definition?

If you are showing an upper bound on the dimension it suffices to look at certain covers. The infimum over all covers will only make it smaller.

@stochastic-conch Then how do I compute the precise dimension from the definition? Sorry, I forgot to add this in my question.

Let $S$ denote the Sierpinski triangle and let
$$
s = \frac{\log(3)}{\log(2)} = \log_2(3).
$$
For completeness sake, let's review the easy part, namely
$$
\dim(S) \leq s.
$$
To prove this it suffices to show that that, for every $\delta>0$, there is some covering $\cal{U}$ of $S$ such that
$$
\sum_{U\in\cal{U}} \text{diam}(U)^s \leq 1.
$$
So, let $\delta>0$ and choose $n \in \mathbb N$ so that $1/2^n < \delta$. We then consider the natural, $n^{\text{th}}$ level covering of $S$ consisting of $3^n$ triangles of side length $1/2^n$. Note that the side length of an equilateral triangle is also the diameter of that triangle. Thus, for this covering, we have
$$
\sum_{U\in\cal{U}} \text{diam}(U)^s = 3^n (1/2^n)^{\log_2(3)} = 1.
$$
It's worth mentioning that this proof works for self-similar sets in general, when all pieces have the same size. Even for fractals that are not self-similar, it's often not too hard to find an upper bound for the Hausdorff dimension by considering some reasonable covering.
Now, the lower bound, namely
$$
\dim(S) \geq s,
$$
is much trickier, as is generally the case in the computation of Hausdorff dimension. I guess we now need to consider sums of the form
$$
\sum_{U\in\cal{U}} \text{diam}(U)^{s'},
$$
where $s'\leq s$ and consider the infima over all such sums. The problem is that we now want a lower bound on the sum so it no longer suffices to find a single cover satisfying a particular inequality, rather we must prove an inequality holds for all covers.
Typically this is done by constructing some measure on the fractal and using that measure to obtain the bound. A whole collection of tools along these lines are described in Chapter 4 of Falconer's Fractal Geometry: Mathematical Foundations and Applications.  The following lemma, for example, appears as theorem 4.2, his so-called "Mass distribution principle":

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $F$ so that $\mu(F)>0$ and suppose that for some $s$ there are numbers $c>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $$\mu(U) \leq c\,\text{diam}(U)^s$$
for all sets $U$ with $\text{diam}(U) \leq \delta$. Then $${\cal H}^s(F) \geq \mu(U)/c.$$

It follows, of course, that $\dim(F) \geq s$.
The proof is both simple and instructive: If $\{U_i\}$ is any cover of $F$, then
$$
0 < \mu(F) = \mu\left(\bigcup_i U_i\right) \leq \sum_i \mu(U_i) \leq c \sum_i \text{diam}(U_i)^s.
$$
Taking infima for $\delta$-covers we find that
$${\cal H}_{\delta}^s (F) \geq \mu(F)/c,$$
for small enough $\delta$ so that
$${\cal H}^s (F) \geq \mu(F)/c$$
To apply this to the Sierpinski triangle, $S$, we need to construct a measure on $S$ satisfying the desired hypotheses. To do so, we first construct a sequence of measures. We start with a measure $\mu_0$ satisfying $\mu_0(S)=1$. We then choose a measure $\mu_1$ with the property that each of the 3 triangles at the level 1 construction of $S$ has measure $1/3$. In general, we choose a measure $\mu_n$ so that each of the $3^n$ triangles of diameter $1/2^n$ at the $n^{\text{th}}$ level of the construction has measure $1/3^n$.
Now, it seems reasonable to hope that this sequence of measures might converge in some sense. It requires some knowledge of functional analysis to get there, though. In particular, we can place a topology on the set of all measures on $S$ called the weak-* topology. The set of all measures assigning $\mu(S)=1$ turn out to be compact in this topology; thus, there is a cluster point. Such a point in this space is exactly the measure $\mu$ that we need.
With this measure $\mu$ in hand, we can proceed because, while $\mu$ may seem fairly mysterious, one thing we know about $\mu$ is that
$$\mu(T) = 1/3^n,$$
whenever $T$ is one of the triangles at the $n^{\text{th}}$ level of construction of $S$.
So finally, let $U$ be a set whose diameter is less than 1 and let $k$ be the integer such that
$$\frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \leq \text{diam}(U) < \frac{1}{2^k}.$$
A glance at a tessellation by congruent, equilateral triangles of side length $1/2^k$ should convince you that $U$ can intersect no more than 7 of those triangles. Thus, this same bound should work for the number of triangles that $U$ can intersect in the $k^{\text{th}}$ level construction of $S$. That gives us
$$\mu(U) \leq 7 \times \frac{1}{3^k} = 7 \times \left(\frac{1}{2^k}\right)^{\log(3)/\log(2)} \leq 7 \times \left(2 \, \text{diam}(U)\right)^{\log(3)/\log(2)}.$$

If you are interested in the computation of Hausdorff measure at a more fundamental level, then I strongly recommend Falconer's text and, especially, chapter 4. This answer is largely based on section 4.1 of that text and is something of a modification of the example that he works out for the Cantor set there.
Falconer does gloss over some measure theoretic issues; I don't think that he even mentions the weak-* topology, for example. He does pretty good job of explaining the necessary measure theory from an intuitive perspective, though.
If you want an introductory text that's deals more fully and completely with measure theory, then I'd recommend Measure, Topology, and Fractal Geometry, by Gerald Edgar.
